# ParseFile.getUrl()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am calling the images from parse cloud and loading them into my gridview holder using picasso.

Here is doInbackGround

```
@Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... Params) {
           feedsarraylist = new ArrayList<ParseFeeds>();
           try {
               ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("AroundMe");
               query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
               //query.whereWithinKilometers()
               ob = query.find();

               for (ParseObject feeds : ob) {
                   ParseFile thumb = (ParseFile) feeds.get("videoThumbs");
                   //ParseFile video = (ParseFile) feeds.get("file");
                   ParseFeeds map = new ParseFeeds();
                   //map.setImage(thumb.getUrl());
                  //Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(video.getUrl());
                   map.setImage(thumb.getUrl());
                   feedsarraylist.add(map);
               }

           } catch (ParseException e) {
               Log.e("ParseException", "parse: " + e);
           }
           return null;
       }
```

ParseFeeds.class

```
   public String getImage() {
        return videoThumbs;
    }

    public void setImage(String videoThumbs) {
        this.videoThumbs = videoThumbs;
    }
```

This where I load it into GridViewAdapter.class

```
  Picasso.with(context).load(feedsarraylist.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.ThumbView);
```

Logcat details

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.parse.ParseFile.getUrl()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.teamtreehouse.ribbit.FeedsFragment$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(FeedsFragment.java:67)
                                                                              at com.teamtreehouse.ribbit.FeedsFragment$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(FeedsFragment.java:45)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, because you didn't specify where the error occurs.

```
ParseFile thumb = (ParseFile) feeds.get("videoThumbs");
map.setImage(thumb.getUrl())
```

If `feeds` does not have the `videoThumbs` elements, `thumb` will be `null` and therefore your error. Check the contents of your `feeds` element.

Comment: I have videoThumbs column in the Parse Class.

Comment: do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @Savita You'd better ensure your `ParseFile` contains `videoThumbs` before you get it. Log it and find out where set `videoThumbs` failed. Maybe it is set after your get it.

Comment: Just debug your code and inspect the value of feeds.

Comment: @RvdK I have added the logcat. The videoThumbs column does exits in my parse class